# Using HTML/JS/CSS Only - Is there a way to render a color image in Black & White?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Given a color image, is there a styling you could apply to the image tag to make it look black and white in the browser? I've seen IE only solutions which is surprising :) Usually it's the opposite.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: IE did in fact make these kinds of filters available since v4 I think, but afaik there are no CSS or HTML ways to do it.

Comment: Do you mean [greyscale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) or [thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing))?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562135/how-do-you-convert-a-color-image-to-black-white-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you've only seen IE solutions is because it's not part of CSS. IE - as always - decided to go their own way and add a bunch of non standard filters :)

If you can use HTML 5, you can use the canvas tag and do something like this: http://spyrestudios.com/html5-canvas-image-effects-black-white/

Otherwise, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: [You can do it (in Firefox) with SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css/4028908#4028908)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, thanks for the info! Unfortunately, in my book, a FF-only solution is just as bad as an IE-only solution. Anyone that intentionally targets the non-standard feature set of one browser is asking for trouble and is arguably holding the Internet back.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure jQuery solution, there is a plugin called [Image Desaturate](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/desaturate).

Otherwise, check out [Desaturate Images Using Javascript](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html) and the [Pixastic library for Desaturate](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/).

I found these quickly via a simple Google search for "`javascript desaturate`" and "`javascript desaturate jquery`."

Comment: These plugins still use the `<canvas>` tag. They just hide it away so the developer doesn't need to know how it is happening. Probably that is what you meant by "pure jQuery" but I wasn't sure if you were saying that jQuery is able to desaturate an image on its own.

Comment: I meant pure jQuery as in sticking with one library, but with an added plugin.