# How to automaticly generate a black and white version of a picture

Tags: php, javascript, image-processing, colors

I have logo parade in WordPress. All those logo are color RGB. I like the effect that look like. All the logo are b&W and then on hover it become color.

I know how to do it with sprite, but it just double each logo and i have a lot. i know it's possible to "process it" with php or JavaScript to "generate" the b&w version on the fly.

What will be the best way/code to do that ?

Comment: js is not really good for it. check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/562135/1164491

Comment: I wouldn't worry about doubling the amount of logos. Grayscale pictures likely compress to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And that wordpress technique look cool : http://bavotasan.com/2011/create-black-white-thumbnail-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of images I would not recommend you to generate grayscale version on the fly. Better to prepare corresponding black and white version for each icon/logo. It's very easy to do for example with ImageMagick:

```
$ mogrify -channel RGBA -matte -colorspace gray *.png
```

This will conver all the `.png` images to the grayscale.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that perfect solution (by luck) : https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/jQuery.BlackAndWhite will try all and tell you wich one win, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browsers you want to support, you may be able to [do it using CSS filters](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#grayscaleEquivalent). However, support for this is not very widespread at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it for every image, you cane us this formula, using the range [0-255]:

Grayscale value = (0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b);

where r, g, b represent the red, green and blue values of the input images.